# How to filter a one-to-one generic relation with Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a moderation model :

```
class ItemModeration(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['object_id', 'content_type']),
        ]
        unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id')

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    item = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

A descriptor to attach a moderation object on-the-fly :

```
class ItemModerationDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, **default_kwargs):
        self.default_kwargs = default_kwargs

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        try:
            moderation = ItemModeration.objects.get(content_type__pk=ctype.id,
                                                    object_id=instance.pk)
        except ItemModeration.DoesNotExist:
            moderation = ItemModeration(item=instance,**self.default_kwargs)
            moderation.save()
        return moderation
```

And a model I want to moderate :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    created = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=True, null=True,
    )
    modified = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True,
        blank=True, null=True,
    )
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=PRODUCT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH,
        blank=True, null=True,
    )
    moderation = ItemModerationDescriptor()
```

Now I can see a product 'published' state easily :

```
p=Product(name='my super product')
p.save()
print(p.moderation.published)
-> False
```

The generic relation is useful because I will be able to search the objects to moderate whatever the type is : it could be products, images, comments.

```
 to_moderate_qs = ItemModeration.objects.filter(published=False)
```

Now, how can I get a filtered list of published products ?
I would like to do something like this

```
published_products_qs = Product.objects.filter(moderation__published=True, name__icontains='sony')
```

But, of course, it won't work as `moderation` attribute is not a Django model field.

How can I do that efficiently ? I am thinking a about an appropriate JOIN, but I cannot see how to do that with django without using raw SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a great built in answer for this: the [GenericRelation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations).  Instead of your descriptor, just define a generic relation on your `Product` model and use it as a normal related field:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    moderation = GenericRelation(ItemModeration)
```

Then handle creation as you normally would with a related model, and filtering should work exactly as you stipulated.  To work as your current system, you'd have to put in a hook or `save` method to create the related `ItemModeration` object when creating a new `Product`, but that's no different from other related django models.  If you really want to keep the descriptor class, you can obviously make use of a secondary model field for the `GenericRelation`.

You can also add `related_query_name` to allow filtering the `ItemModeration` objects based only on the `Product` content type.

**WARNING** if you *do* use a `GenericRelation` note that it has a fixed cascading delete behavior.  So if you don't want `ItemModeration` object to be deleted when you delete the `Product`, be careful to add a pre_delete hook or equivalent!

#### Update

I unintentionally ignored the `OneToOne` aspect of the question because the `GenericForeignKey` is a one-to-many relation, but similar functionality can be effected via smart use of QuerySets.  It's true, you don't have access to `product.moderation` as a single object.  But, for example, the following query iterates over a filtered list of products and extracts their name, the user's username, and the published date of the related `ModerationItem`:

```
Product.objects.filter(...).values_list(
    'name', 'user__username', 'moderation__published'
)
```

Comment: I know this relation, the filtering works like you said, but it is more for 'many-to-many' than one-to-one cases. If you do a product.moderation : you do not have an object, but a queryset. This implies to make another query for each row of product you get. for exemple : [ (i.name,i.moderation.first().an_attribute_I_want) for i in Product.objects.filter(moderation__published=True, name__icontains='sony').prefetch_related('moderation') ] this will generate a LOT of queries. I was expecting 1 or 2.

Comment: I think I addressed this in the update.  But I could be missing something.  Please let me know if I got it wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah !! too easy! manage.py shell_plus --print-sql showed me only one request to the database and I got the genericity, the filtering and the fields I want. Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the `content_type` to query the table by specific model type.

like this:

```
product_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Product)
unpublished_products = ItemModeration.objects.filter(content_type__pk=product_type.id, published=False)
```

For more details on the topic check [contenttypes doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/)

Comment: It is not exactly what I expect : your queryset returns ItemModeration objects, not Product object. of course I get product from itemModeration. But the main point is that I would like to do some filtering on Product fields, ie name__icontains='sony'. I modified the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Eric sorry for the late reply, you can do all other filtrations over `product` since it's a `OneToOne` relationship